# Setting up new project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

So I set up a new project into Eclipse and created a build.xml that creates a war file. The problem that I am having is that the only files that are included in the war are what's in the WEB-INF. How do you include my web folder into the war?

- Project

  - src
  - web
  - WEB-INF

Comment: Showing a bit more of your build.xml would be really useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(edited for correctness and clarity)

Assuming Project Setup as follows:

- Project

  - src (java source files)
  - web (web content)
  - WEB-INF (with at least a web.xml inside)
  - build (build.xml is here)

Here's a quick ant script to war it up:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="sample" basedir="../" default="war">

    <target name="compile">
        <delete dir="build/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="compile">
        <war destfile="myWar.war" webxml="WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="web"/>
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
            <webinf dir="WEB-INF"/>
        </war>
    </target>

</project>
```

See the Ant user manual for the [`war` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your WEB-INF should be below the web folder.  Classes should go in web/WEB-INF/classes.

Build the finished layout and then use the WAR task to wrap it up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referring to a build.xml file, I'll assume you are using Ant (or Eclipse is using it for you.) If that is the case, you want to use the *war* Ant task and its *includes* attribute (or *fileset* nested task) to list your web directory for inclusion in the resulting war.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html

Assuming you are using an older Ant distribution that lacks the *war* task, use the *jar* task, which *war* inherits from.

I don't know what your build.xml looks like, but I would venture to guess it has a *war* or *jar* task. Using its *includes* attribute, it should look something like this (this is from the top of my head, you might need to tweak it to compile for your specific situation):

```
<war destfile="your.war" webxml="src/metadata/your.xml">
  <fileset dir="src"/>
  <fileset dir="web"/>
  <classes dir="build/classes"/>
</war>
```

Without seeing your build.xml, it is impossible to tell if this suggestion is applicable or not, though.